# 550 error when sending email through nodemailer

Tags: smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to use nodemailer for the first time for a contact form and am having a hell of a time getting this to work. It seems like no matter what I do, I get the following error:

```
Error: Mail command failed: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 Sender address is not allowed.
```

From scouring the internet, it seems this is somehow related to the account where I want to receive the message rejecting the email. The problem is I'm struggling to find a clear solution for how to properly handle this, or how to be sure that that is indeed the problem.

My general assumption is there is something, or several somethings, that I'm just unaware of since I'm sort of a noob to nodemailer and smtp generally. I'm including all relevant code snippets below, thanks in advance for any helpful hints on this one. Personal info has been removed in the below code (creds data and mail.to).

Frontend submit function in react component:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const name = this.state.name;
    const email = this.state.email;
    const message = this.state.message;

    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/send',
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            message: message
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.msg === 'success') {
            alert('Message sent');
            this.resetForm();
        } else if (response.data.msg === 'fail') {
            alert('Message failed to send.');
        }
    })
  };
```

Backend routes and nodemailer code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const creds = require('./config');

const transport = {
    host: 'smtp.mail.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: creds.USER,
        pass: creds.PASS
    }
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {    
        console.log('Server is ready for messages');
    }
});

router.post('/send', (request, response, next) => {
    const name = request.body.name;
    const email = request.body.email;
    const message = request.body.message;
    const content = `name: ${name} \n email: ${email} \n message: ${message}`;

    const mail = {
        from: name,
        to: 'MY GMAIL ACCOUNT WHERE I WANT TO RECIEVE THE MESSAGE',
        subject: 'New message from tyleranyan.com',
        text: content
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            response.json({
                msg: 'fail'
            });
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            response.json({
                msg: 'success'
            });
        }
    });
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(4000);
```

Config file for creds:

```
module.exports = {
    USER: 'THE EMAIL THAT IS SENDING THE MESSAGE, IN THIS CASE A MAIL.COM EMAIL ADDRESS', 
    PASS: 'PASSWORD FOR SENDER EMAIL'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems this all centered around the sender email I was using and some weirdness with the smtp address.

It's kind of an odd one-off, but for what it's worth: mail.com allows you to create a free email account with a customized domain. So in this case, I had something along the lines of: "myName@mindless.com" with an smtp of "smtp.mail.com" and that was simply not working. I made a second gmail account, enabled less secure apps, updated the creds info and smtp address, and it's now working beautifully.